# Problems installing winehq

Tags: release-loki, wine

i want to install wine (https://www.winehq.org/) and from what i have seen elementary is a debian based distro, but when i try to install using the `deb` command it says it can't find it. What can i do?

Thanks in regards, Davin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In elementary OS you can install wine either via the *AppCenter* (search for `wine` and click *Install*) or via the command line:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

Comment: can't install it from the appcenter but the command worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I had to follow the link below before I could install WINEHQ because I keep getting the command not found.

https://itsfoss.com/add-apt-repository-command-not-found/

after you fix the command not found issue go back to wineHQ and the installs will work.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand. Have a nice day!